# Group items into dropdown menu when collapsed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar, nav

I have just found this type of collapse navbar from a site, all menu items grouped into a dropdown menu and positioned right, its different from usual bootstrap collapse navbar

Sorry for having not enough reputations to post image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILfpJ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Syovo.png

I have tried many suggestions but it didnt work exactly like what theirs did, the result is always full vertical dropdown menu

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6yYR.png

My code

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg py-0" style="background-color: #0d47a1;">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/dashboard/">
            <img src="/images/logo.webp" width="40" height="40" alt="">
        </a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item px-2">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Shop Manager</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item px-2">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Customer Care</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item px-2">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Messenger Order</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a little custom css to get the menu smaller that full width:

```
.navbar-collapse {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 40px;
  background-color: #333;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
    background-color: transparent;
    position: initial; /* Using 'initial' here rather than specificing 'relative'.*/
  }
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettgaynor/8sh70Ldb/10/) showing it working. You can customize it form there to get it looking like the examples you provided, but that's the rough idea.

Comment: yes it works, but when resize the page to 100% the nav items still be there, they dont back to navbar as before 
https://i.imgur.com/9JTKCt1.png

Comment: Right. You'd need to add a media query to return the postioning and background to their initial values. I've updated the fiddle and my answer to reflect this.

Comment: thanks, now im adding a sidebar into, but a gap appears between it and top navbar when resizing to smaller view, can you help ?
https://www.codeply.com/go/XHDeSP3Fzv

Comment: Based on your example, the easiest fix is to add a `min-height: 56px;` to your `.navbar`. That will just keep the height the same when the "hamburger" menu collapses.

Comment: Is the default height of topnav 56px ?

Comment: Not necessarily. I just took the size it was based on what shows up when inspecting with devtool. If you adjust your font size of the links in the nav, then that height may have to be adjusted.